# alternative of usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, controls, webforms

Is there any other alternative of usercontrol other than webpart and iframe, Which i can use in my asp.net application.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are usercontrol, webpart and iframe not suitable to your scenario? What is your scenario?

Comment: actually i am creating a customize dashboard which user can customize as their own choices in our scenario performance is major issue...currently we are using usercontrols but is there any other better option or opinion which we can use, other than iframe because we are not interested in it as it involves some restrictions like browser's print print whats you see in the page including the iframe etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are trying to achieve but at the top of my head I can say you can use an update panel to act as a type of iframe to load another page inside your page.

Answer (score 0):

User control is already as abstract as possible: it's final and ultimate goal is to send something to the browser, based on parameters you give it from the server side. Label has `Text` property that once set, send `<span>` tag to the browser with that given text. `Panel` has collection of children that when set are sent to the browser wrapped in `<div>` element. Etc Etc..

So the direct answer is: no, no alternative.

However, based on your comment, there might be a way to improve the performance.. what control you currently have? How user can customize them? If you can explain better the scenario and post some relevant code it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment on the question, Using usercontrols along with placeholders and some jQuery plugins OR simply web parts controls as containers is fine.

No need to change it unless you have a problem with it. Then we might discuss other options like Custom Server controls etc.. but those also have their issues, etc.. so it's always a balance.

If you have no problem and want to check whether this is the right thing that you do or something else, then I think the answer is, yeah. Unless you have specific issues, this way seems OK to go.